# How to change the ORDER ID generator algorithm in woocommerce to something else?

Tags: php, wordpress, algorithm

My question is simple (hopefuly)

Currently in a Woocommerce store the order ID of each order is (i presume) a random set of characters.

How can we change this and put in that place an algorithm? For example instead of having order ids like:  0134 0763 0176 , i want to have something like order id = x*3 where x will be the number of post/order. so the first order will have order ID = 3 , the second order will jhave order ID = 6 , the third 9 etc etc

is there a way to go around that with more complex aglorithms?

Comment: I honestly have no idea on where to even begin with. I just need something to start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The woocommerce order id is not an random number.The technical reason WooCommerce order numbers appear in this seemingly random sequence is simply because a WooCommerce Order record is represented within the database by a WordPress Post and the post id is used as the order id.
But if you want to represent the order numbers in sequence or you want to set the starting number for order, or add a custom prefix/suffix to your order numbers you can use Plugin like [WooCommerce Sequential Order Numbers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-sequential-order-numbers/)